# Form not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've got the following javascript that loads a form into a hidden div on the page and the shows the div

```
function load() {
    ...stuff to get date and id...
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState==4&&xhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("PopupDiv").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("PopupDiv").removeAttribute("hidden");
            alert(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "Object?date=" + date + "&id=" + id, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

this loads a partial view with the following:

```
<h2>@Model.date</h2>
<h2>@Model.id</h2>
<div id="OptionsDiv">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Plan",FormMethod.Post,new { id = "OptionsForm" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.date)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.id)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.options)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.options, Model.optionsDropdown)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.comment)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.comment)
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
</div>
<p>test after the div</p>
```

when the javascript event is triggered, it is all loaded in correctly when viewing the DOM explorer, but the form is not shown. info before and after is shown, but nothing  within the form.

the alert from the response contains:

```
<h2>5/12/2016 12:00:00 AM</h2>

<h2>13</h2>

<div id="OptionsDiv">

<form action="/Plan/Confirm" id="PlanOptionsForm" method="post"><input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field date must be a date." data-val-required="The date field is required." id="date" name="date" type="hidden" value="5-12-2016" /><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="13" /><label for="Options">options</label><select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field meal must be a number." data-val-required="The meal field is required." id="meal" name="meal"><option selected="selected" value="0">--Choose an Option--</option>

<option value="1">Option 1</option>

<option value="2">Option 2</option>

<option value="3">Option 3</option>

<option value="4">Option 4</option>

</select>        <br />

<label for="comment">comment</label><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field servings must be a number." data-val-required="The comment field is required." id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="0" />        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form></div>

<p>test after the div</p>
```

If I go into the DOM explorer and select the different parts, they will show up, but the initial load looks like:

[image: screenshot]

It all shows up correctly in Chrome and Firefox

Also, removing the other form on the page does not solve the problem.

Comment: Does your page contain a `form` around `popupDiv`?

Comment: There is another form on the page but it does not contain my popupDiv

Comment: If `popupDiv` isn't inside the form then it works in Edge as expected.
If `popupDiv` is inside form then Edge (and FF) removes internal `form` and keep external one. Content of the internal form is shown. Submit goes to external form action. This is what I found from experiment. Nested forms are not allowed. EI 11 does the same.  
Check content of your xhr response.

Comment: It's not nested. It's in a separate div and the first one is definitely closed. both form tags are visible when viewing the source of the page. I also added my response text

Comment: What is the doctype? You can get it by writing `document.doctype` in the javascript console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, you can't load a form into a hidden element.

I changed the order in my JavaScript function from:

```
document.getElementById("PopupDiv").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("PopupDiv").removeAttribute("hidden");
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("PopupDiv").removeAttribute("hidden");
document.getElementById("PopupDiv").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

and now it works.

Comment: I used either way and the form appeared and worked in all browsers.